# Issue with apache2.conf Apache Web Server (2.4) for LoadModule

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I want to use mod_proxy on my Apache Web Server v2.4 (latest as of 23 Dec 2023).

Since I could not find the good old httpd.conf file, I am trying to use apache2.conf (on Ubuntu 22.04 under /etc/apache2).

However when I try to add the mod_proxy code in the file, the Server crashes:

Here is how I am trying to add the code:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

I am struggling - what wrong am I doing?

Singham